# How do i change the color multiplier of a lightingColorFilter instance

Tags: android, canvas

Based on the doc,

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/LightingColorFilter.html

it seems like the LightingColorFilter class only has a constructor. (Same to its parent class, ColorFilter)

How do i keep only ONE instance of LightingColorFilter while having the flexibility to modify the color properties for that filter instance?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it is possible to change the filter after it is instanciated.

You would need to create a new filter for each color you want to use.

It's not cool :(